# Как правильно спроектировать web сервис?

Tags: веб-программирование, spring, csv

У меня есть csv файл(большой), я его считываю в БД. потом нужно по этим считанным данным сформировать отчет. и тут вопрос, как делать эти отчеты?
на данный момент для формирования каждого отчета я хожу в БД и работает это очень долго(т.к. > 100т записей). как ускорить обработку? на данный момент есть идея подключить кеширование, но раньше с ним не работал, так что не знаю насколько это ускорит процесс.

И еще пара вопросов:

- я использую Spring Data, и для некоторых отчетов использую @Query(sql запрос), такой подход целесообразен или лучше выгрузить все данные куда-то и руками все делать?
- как правильно вызвать метод в контроллере, который выгружает данные из csv в БД? На данный момент у меня в конструкторе контроллера это происходит:

  ```
  @Autowired
  public Controller(Service service) {
      this.service= service;
      service.saveDataToDB();
  }
  ```

  Но такой способ сильно режет глаз и я подозреваю, что это неправильно

Comment: 100 000 записей - это очень мало, надо постараться чтобы их обработка была медленной.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev посмотрел, обработка идет быстро. проблема заключается в том, что я вызываю метод findAll(), который долго считывает данные из БД. мне не нравится, что я считываю данные из csv в бд, а потом еще несколько раз обращаюсь к бд за теми же данными.

Answer (score 1):

по определенным ошибкам БД разрослась до >1млн записей, поэтому работало долго. тем не менее, подключил кэш и повесил индекс на таблицу-> стало быстрее отрабатывать(потом от ошибки избавился)